# Did the base OS image ever contain a Linux kernel to begin with?

Tags: docker

Quick question which I can't find anywhere. I know that the built Docker image does NOT contain the Linux kernel.

When building a Dockerfile with `FROM Ubuntu:latest`.

1. Does the Ubuntu image contain the kernel and is stripped.
2. The Ubuntu image never included the kernel to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will be **answer 2**.
Docker image never includes the kernel. For Ubuntu, you can check it [here](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/tree/010bf9649b1d10e2c34b159a9a9b338d0fdd4939/bionic). That's the Github repo of the **latest** tag.
You'll find that the dockerfile mainly copy the tar archive and extract it.

Answer (score 1):

No, base image is related to `Union file systems`, while kernel is related to `Namespaces`, `cgroups`, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#the-underlying-technology).

So, all container will share the kernel of host, not related with base image, base image just related with `Union file systems`:

[image]

A good article maybe also help your [here](https://medium.com/@nagarwal/understanding-the-docker-internals-7ccb052ce9fe).

Answer (score -1):

You are using the kernel from your host. Docker is intended to isolate the process, disks, network but maps calls to the host kernel.